# He efectuados varios CRUD con gii, y unos funcionan y otros no insertan los datos

Tags: yii2

Tengo varias tablas en un sistema, y ​​he creado 30 CRUD con GII de yii2. Luego los ajusto a mis necesidades, y los últimos 7 CRUD que he creado no insertan los valores en las tablas, no mostrando errores mas que el mensaje flash incluido que  dice Error!!! El registro no fue guardado.
Al ingresar registros directamente en mysql por consola, estos registros si se pueden editar y modificar perfectamente, solo que no se puede ingresar datos desde el sistema.

Por favor me pueden ayudar.
Controlador ItemsController.php

```
<?php

namespace app\modules\admin\controllers;

use Yii;
use app\models\Items;
use app\models\ItemsSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;

/**
 * ItemsController implements the CRUD actions for Items model.
 */
class ItemsController extends MyController
{
    /**
     * Lists all Items models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new ItemsSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays a single Items model.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Items model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Items();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

            if ( $model->save() ) {
                $this->msgFlashSuccessCreate($model);
            } else {
                $this->msgFlashErrorCreate($model);
            }
            return $this->redirect(['index']);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing Items model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

            if ( $model->save() ) {
                $this->msgFlashSuccessUpdate($model);
            } else {
                $this->msgFlashErrorUpdate($model);
            }
            return $this->redirect(['index']);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing Items model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    /**
     * Finds the Items model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return Items the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = Items::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        }

        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }
}
```

Class MyController 
MyController.php

```
<?php

namespace app\modules\admin\controllers;

use Yii;
// use app\models\Facturacion;
// use app\models\FacturacionSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;

/**
 * FacturacionController implements the CRUD actions for Facturacion model.
 */
class MyController extends Controller
{
    public $layout = 'template';
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function msgFlashErrorCreate($model)
    {
        $model = new $model();

                Yii::$app->session->setFlash("error", "Error!!! El registro no fue guardado");
    }

    public function msgFlashSuccessCreate($model)
    {
        $model = new $model();

        Yii::$app->session->setFlash("success", "Registro guardado exitosamente");
    }

    public function msgFlashErrorUpdate($model)
    {
        $model = new $model();

                Yii::$app->session->setFlash("error", "Error!!! El registro no fue modificado");
    }

    public function msgFlashSuccessUpdate($model)
    {
        $model = new $model();

        Yii::$app->session->setFlash("success", "Registro modificado exitosamente");
    }
}

Modelo Items.php

    <?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "items".
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $item
 * @property int $grupo
 * @property string $created_at
 * @property string $updated_at
 * @property int $created_by
 * @property int $updated_by
 */
class Items extends MyActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'items';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['item', 'grupo'], 'required'],
            [['grupo', 'created_by', 'updated_by'], 'integer'],
            [['created_at', 'updated_at'], 'safe'],
            [['item'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'item' => 'Item',
            'grupo' => 'Grupo',
            'created_at' => 'Created At',
            'updated_at' => 'Updated At',
            'created_by' => 'Created By',
            'updated_by' => 'Updated By',
        ];
    }
}
```

Class MyActiveRecord
MyActiveRecord.php

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\db\Expression;
use yii\behaviors\BlameableBehavior;

/** 
 * Modelo con la clase MiActiveRecor
 * Metodo Behaviors par toda la aplicación
*/

class MyActiveRecord extends ActiveRecord
{ 
    public function Behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'timestamp' => [
                'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
                'attributes' => [
                    ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => ['created_at', 'updated_at'],
                    ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => ['updated_at']
                ],
                'value' => new Expression('NOW()'),
            ],
             'blameable' => [
                 'class' => BlameableBehavior::className(),
                 'createdByAttribute' => 'created_by',
                 'updatedByAttribute' => 'updated_by',

            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getCreatedBy()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Users::className(), ['id' => 'created_by']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getUpdatedBy()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Users::className(), ['id' => 'updated_by']);
    }

    public function getNombres()
    {
        return $this->nombre . " " . $this->apellidos;
    }
}
y la vista
_form.php

    <?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\Items */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="contenido-admin">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'item')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'grupo')->textInput() ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Guardar', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

Comment: si puedes pon el codigo de algun crud que te falla

Comment: algo de que te puede ayudar es que la variable del modelo tiene una propiedad que es un array llamado errors que almacena mensaje de errores

Comment: Edite con el código, Controlador Modelo y Vista: Gracias

Comment: Si en los metodos que tienes para mostrar el mensaje flash , no creas un new model y simplemente pillas el $model que viene por parametro y le haces un print_r($model->errors);die(); te puede dar mucha informacion del error

Comment: Solucionado gracias a print_r($model->errors);die(); created_at y updated_at, no pueden estar vacios, los saque de required y funcionó

Comment: @ClaudioGonzález la "respuesta" que diste como solución en realidad no funciona para solucionar este problema, únicamente sirve para depurar y mostrar que sucede.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una buena forma de depurar los modelos en Yii2 es usar la propiedad del modelo errors.
Es un array asociativo con los errores que ha encontrado en el caso que falle el metodo save.

```
print_r($model->errors);
```

Comment: Esto sirve para depurar pero  no sirve para corregir el error planteado en la pregunta, te sugiero revisar [answer].

Comment: A mi se me olvido eliminar created_at y updated_at del required, cuando los incluí en ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => ['created_at', 'updated_at'], para que sean ingresados por el sistema.